# Error when updating ReactJS state with complex object

Tags: reactjs, state

When I do something like:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return { previews: [], isLoading: true, error: "", nextCursor: "" };
},
componentDidMount: function(){
  $.ajax("/my-url", {
    method: "GET",
    success: this.previewsReceived,
    failure: this.previewsFailedToReceive
  });
},
previewsReceived: function(previews){
  var tmpState =  { isLoading: false, previews: previews.data, nextCursor: previews.next_cursor, error: "" };
  this.setState(tmpState);
},

previewsFailedToReceive: function(_){
  this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, { error: "", isLoading: false, previews: [], nextCursor: "" }));
},
```

I get the following reactJS error:

```
Uncaught [object Object]
```

on line `1093` in the react.js library (in the method `invariant`).

If I am not passing any complex object (inside my `previews` data) to the state however, I do not get the error.

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Edit: Here is the whole component, addressing the first answer, I still get the same errors.

```
var Creatives = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { previews: [], isLoading: true, error: "", nextCursor: "" };
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    $.ajax("/my-url, {
      method: "GET",
      success: this.previewsReceived.bind(this),
      failure: this.previewsFailedToReceive.bind(this)
    });
  },
  previewsReceived: function(previews){
    var tmpState =  { isLoading: false, previews: previews.data, nextCursor: previews.next_cursor, error: "" };
    this.setState(tmpState);
  },

  previewsFailedToReceive: function(_){
    this.setState({ error: "", isLoading: false, previews: [], nextCursor: "" });
  },

  render: function() {
    return <ul>
      {this.state.previews.map(function(creative) {
        return <li key={creative.tweet_id} style="width: 450px">
          <input type="checkbox" style="float:left;margin-top: 10px" />
          <CreativePreview creative={creative} /></li>;
        })
      }
      </ul>;
  }
});
```

I also get the following warning when I call `bind`:

```
Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component.
React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way,
so you can safely remove this call. See Creatives
```

Edit2: I found out that removing most of the render method 'fixes' the error. So I am gonna post the definition of that component too:

```
var CreativePreview = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <iframe
        id={ 'iframe-tweet-id-'+ this.props.creative.tweet_id }
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.props.creative.preview}>
    </iframe>;
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire component, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` works like you want it to on `<iframe>` elements.

You can populate it directly by creating a `ref` to your `<iframe>` element:

```
var CreativePreview = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function(){
    var frame = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myFrame);
    frame.document.body.innerHTML = this.props.creative.preview;
  },
  render: function() {
    return <iframe ref='myFrame' />;
  }
});
```

The error is most likely in `CreativePreview`. Try to remove it to see if it fixes your problem.

Side note: `Object.assign()` calls are unnecessary with React's `setState`. The `setState` method will automatically merge with the current state.

EDIT:
It seems that React will now auto-bind `this` for component functions.

EDIT 2:
Now we can see `CreativePreview`.

Answer (score -1):

There were several errors in my code:

- Inline `class` and `style` in html tags were assuming actual `html` conventions and not `jsx` format.
- The iframe was very hard to implement in reactJS. I found a workaround inspired from https://github.com/ryanseddon/react-frame-component but since it didn't work out of the box, I used vanilla Javascript in it:

--

```
var CreativeFrame = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    var style = { width: '420px', border: 'none', height: '280px' };
    return <iframe
        style={style}
        className="tweet-content"
        id={ "iframe-tweet-id-" + this.props.creative.tweet_id }>
    </iframe>;
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.renderFrameContents();
  },
  renderFrameContents: function() {
    // Proof that good old Javascript >> Any library
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe-tweet-id-" + this.props.creative.tweet_id);
    var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframeDoc.body.innerHTML = this.props.creative.preview;
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function() {
    this.renderFrameContents();
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    var doc = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).contentDocument;
    if (doc) {
      ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(doc.body);
    }
  }
});
```

If anybody knows about improvements on it, let me know.